# Is the right componet of 龍 related to 弱?

Tags: glyph-origin, seal, character-components

The right component of the small seal script 龍 seems to be the mirror image of the components of 弱. I know the older historical forms of 龍 do not share this similarity but I can't help but wonder if this is more than coincidence. Is there any relationship between these components?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, they're not related. The right side of 「龍」 appearing similar to a reflected version of a part of 「弱」 is a coincidence, and is an artefact of seal script shapes.

- 「龍」 was originally a picture of a mythical animal with a long, snake-like body (pic. 1). The right side of 「龍」 is the animal's body, which later separated from the animal's head and incorporated an additional 2-3 decorative strokes (pic. 3).
  <kbd>[商](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shang_dynasty)
  [甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_bone_script)
  [image: 龍]
  [拾](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian/Reference/JiaguwenReference)5.5
  [合集6631](http://www.guoxuedashi.net/jgwhj/?bhfl=1&bh=6631&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[春秋](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_and_Autumn_period)
  [金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
  [image: 龍]
  郘Ｘ鐘
  [集成226](https://www.guoxuedashi.net/yzjwjc/?bh=226&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>[戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[晉](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_(Chinese_state))
  [璽印](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seal_(East_Asia))
  [image: 龍]
  0538
  古璽彙編</kbd>
  <kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
  [image: 龍]
  [龍部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77391&page=135)
  [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd>
- 「弱」 is a reduplication of a component; this component was originally a picture of a person 「人」 urinating (indicated by a shape similar to drops of water, 「氵」). The word that the component originally represented ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)): **/*kə.nˤewk-s/**) is now commonly written as 「尿」, with a less common variant 「溺」. The word meaning *weak* for 「弱」 (**/*newk/**) is a [phonetic loan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_character_classification#Loangraphs).

  | 時期 字體 | 字形｜[隸定](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liding) | 參考資料 |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | 商 甲 | [image: 尿] | [菁](https://www.guoxuedashi.net/zixing/yysm.html)5.1 |
  | 戰國・楚 [簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips) | [image: 溺] | 7 包山楚簡 |
  | 戰國・楚 簡 | [image: 溺] | 老甲12 [郭店楚簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guodian_Chu_Slips) |
  | [秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty) 陶文 | [image: 弱] | 648 秦陶 |
  | [宋楷](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ming_(typefaces)) | [image: 弱] |  |

  The original form (row 1) was duplicated, and in [Chǔ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state)) scripts (rows 2 & 3), (a) one of the 「人」 was corrupted to 「勿」 and (b) one of the 「氵」 become a fully-fledged 「水」 (albeit, written sideways like in 「益」) and disconnected from the person. In [Qín](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty) scripts (row 4), 「人」 was corrupted into 「弓」, leading to the modern 「弱」.

---

**References**:

- 季旭昇《說文新證》

Answer (score 2):

My conclusion after observing the two words is that they are not related.

The right component of 龍 depicts the form of a Loong with spikes on its back;  while 弱 seems to relate to decorative features like 羽 (feather)

The character 弱(weak) came from the image of a decorated bow, which implies it is not as strong as a practical bow

Reference

> [弱](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%BC%B1): deogrammic compound (會意／会意): 弓 (“bow”) + 彡 (“hair, meaning "decoration" in this case”) - a decorative bow that is functionally inferior. Or it might be indicating that the bow is shaking, which implies a worn-out bow.

> [龍](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%BE%8D): Current form developed in large seal script, with serpent’s body on right (tail at upper right, legs on right)